# How can I get a list of all websites and applications running on IIS6?

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server, iis-6

I'm running a Win 2003 server with multiple websites, some of which contain child and grandchild applications (for example see https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x1yi.jpg).

Is there an quick way to obtain a list of all applications? Maybe a script I can run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

http://netomatix.com/EnumWebDirs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [HOWTO: Enumerate IIS website configuration (VBScript using ADSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/howto-enumerate-iis-website-configuration-vbscript-using-adsi)